# How to remove main categories from the url in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to know if there is a way to fixe my issue.
My issue is:
I have the main category:
Ex: Kitchen
sub-categories:
EX: Asian kitchen, african kitchen, american kitchen etc.

When I add a post to the Asian kitchen subcategory the wordpress link is mywebsite.com/kitchen/asian-kitchen/post-name.
What I want to do is remove kitchen from the link.

I also faced another issue with this. the subcategory doesn't work at all. it's showing error 404.
mywebsite.com/kitchen/asian-kitchen is not working.

I will put this links for you to check. Thanks in advance

Post link: https://facmaroc.com/english-studies/semester-one/study-skills-s1/critical-thinking
What I want : https://facmaroc.com/study-skills-s1/critical-thinking

Subcategory showing error link: https://facmaroc.com/english-studies/semester-one/study-skills-s1/

Comment: Just a quick observation, but if you DON'T want child categories, then the simplest solution is to NOT use them.  Other than organizing your categories in the back end, there's no benefit to using child categories if you're stripping them out at a the permalink level.  By using them, you're creating more work for yourself.  You can still assign more than one category to a post, you can make some categories the primary (I think Yoast SEO adds this) and you can still build structured navigation using the Menu settings. I think just not using them is the most efficient answer.

Comment: @TonyDjukic, parent categories can be useful from other reasons even if they’re not explicitly used on the front end, e.g. to group all posts in a particular parent category to be able to add the same fields/template/functionality etc. To just that category. We can’t really tell from the info we have here - the OP might even be displaying the categories on the front end and just wants to remove it from the url. No idea *why* they’d want to, but if that’s what they want...:)